# Insert row if there is text in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA Code:

```
Sub InsertRev()
Dim c As Range
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5000")
For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
    If c.Value Like "*Card Number:*" Then
    c.EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

but it only works if I have specific text in A. Is there way to change if so there's a row inserted above any cell in column A that has text? Can the row also have the same value that was in column A above it (So if A1 has text, row is inserted with the value of A1 (which is now A2)).

Answer (score 1):

"Is there way to change if so there's a row inserted above any cell in column A that has text?"

Instead of:

`If c.Value Like "*Card Number:*" Then`

Write:

`If Len(Trim(c)) Then`

---

"Can the row also have the same value that was in column A above it (So if A1 has text, row is inserted with the value of A1 (which is now A2))."

After     `c.EntireRow.Insert` write:

`If c.Row > 1 Then c.Value = c.Offset(-1).Value`

The `c.Row > 1` check is needed, because if it is the first cell, the `c.Offset(-1)` would trigger an error. [MSDN Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)